# Validación personalizada en FormControl de Angular no funciona

Tags: angular

Tengo una función personalizada **`cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces()`** que elimina los espacios vacíos que están de mas en una cadena de texto.

Quiero que esta función funcione en mi `FormControl`, pero no da resultado.

**category.service.ts**:

```
  cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(control: AbstractControl) {
    const text = control.value;
    return text.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim();
  }
```

**component.ts**:

```
  categoryNameEdit: FormControl;
  
  constructor(
    public categoryService: CategoryService,
  ) {
    this.categoryNameEdit = new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/),
      Validators.maxLength(25),
      Validators.minLength(4),
      this.categoryService.cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces
    ]);
  }
```

**component.html**:

```
<input 
  type="text"
  name="editedName"
  [formControl]="categoryNameEdit"
  class="form-control capitalize"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que lo estas enviando como una validación, esta solo te permite validar mas no modificar el `FormControl`, por lo tanto no es una transformación, lo que necesitas hacer es suscribirte a los cambios a tu control y actualizar el valor en cada cambio.

Usamos `startWith("")` para omitir la validación de que el campo sea nulo.

Al usar `patchVaue` pasamos un objeto con `emitEvent: false` para omitir la propagación del `suscribe` cada vez que actualizamos, de lo contrario entraríamos en un bucle infinito.

```
constructor(public categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categoryNameEdit = new FormControl("");

    this.categoryNameEdit.valueChanges.pipe(startWith("")).subscribe(value => {
      this.categoryNameEdit.patchValue(
        this.categoryService.cleanUnnecessaryWhiteSpaces(value),
        {
          emitEvent: false,
          onlySelf: true
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

> **Nota: No olvides guardar el subscribe en una variable para hacer el unsubscribe() en tu ngOnDestroy.**